# Tornado websocket pings

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I'm running a Python Tornado server with a WebSocket handler.
We've noticed that if we abruptly disconnect the a client (disconnect a cable for example) the server has no indication the connection was broken. No on_close event is raised.
Is there a workaround? 
I've read there's an option to send a ping, but didn't see anyone use it in the examples online and not sure how to use it and if it will address this issue.

Comment: hv u got the answer

Comment: we implemented a ping/pong:
    `def do_ping(self):
        if self.is_active:
            if not self.received_pong:
                self.retries += 1
                if self.retries == 3:
                    logger.info()
                    self.on_close()
                    return
                else:
                    logger.info()
            self.received_pong = False
            self.ping('data')
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().call_later(20, self.do_ping)
 
    def on_pong(self, data):
        self.received_pong = True
        self.retries = 0`

Answer (score 0):

The on_close event can only be triggered when the connection is closed.

You can send a `ping` and wait for an `on_pong` event.

Timouts are typically hard to detect since you won't even get a message that the socket is closed.

Comment: could u share an example